# Difference between WD2003FZEX and WD2003FYPS WD desktop HDDs

Tags: hard-drive, desktop-computer

Whats is the difference between this models Western Digital Black 2TB HDDs models: WD2003FZEX vs WD2003FYPS ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are not both WD Black models.

The WD2003FZEX is a WD Black 2TB

The WD2003FYPS is a WD RE4 2TB

WD = Western Digital
2003 = indicates the drive is 2 TB and the '3' is an additional product code
four letters = this shows what type of drive it is

The major difference between Black and RE4 is the [TLER setting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_recovery_control#Desktop_computers_and_TLER) which is activated for the RE4 and additional vibration tolerance for the RE4. 
These functions are intended for use in servers and RAIDs,
so unless you're planning this you can just get a WD Black.

From personal experience: the RE4 is less loud and makes a less annoying sound but you'll have to take my word for it :)

You can find an explanation of the WD naming convention
at the [WD Model Numbers Info Sheet](http://studylib.net/doc/8686511/wd-model-numbers-info-sheet). 
[[Alternative URL](http://manualzz.com/doc/8940430/model-number-format-for-wd-internal-drive-products)]

> WD’s model number format simplifies inventory management
>   for distributors and system manufacturers. 
>   Capacity points are key to this format.
>
> #### Base Model Number
>
> The base model number is composed of six codes:
>
> 1. Company initials (WD)
> 2. Capacity (GB/TB)
> 3. Capacity unit/form factor
> 4. Business unit/brand
> 5. RPM/buffer size or attribute
> 6. Interface/connector
>
>    ```
>                                    WD 0000 A B C D
>                                    —— ———— — — — —
>                                    ↑  ↑    ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑
>                                    1  2    3 4 5 6
>    ```
>
> #### Model Number Codes
>
> 1. **Company Initials**
>      WD
> 2. **Capacity**
>      Two, three, or four digits, supports up to 999.9.
>
>    For 1 TB and larger WD Black™ and enterprise drives, the decimal
>      follows the first digit (e.g., WD1000FYPS is a 1 TB capacity drive). 
>      These drives also use the last digit of the capacity number as a
>      product code (e.g., WD2003FYYS). 
>      This digit does *not* translate to additional capacity/LBAs.
> 3. **Capacity Unit/Form Factor**
>      A GB/3.5-inch
>      B GB/2.5-inch
>      C TB/2.5-inch
>      D TB/2.5- to 3.5-inch backplane adapter
>      E TB/3.5-inch
>      F TB/3.5-inch (new format)
>      G GB/2.5- to 3.5-inch adapter
>      H GB/2.5- to 3.5-inch backplane adapter
>      J TB/2.5-inch
>      K GB/2.5-inch (12.5 mm z-height)
>      L GB/2.5-inch (7 mm z-height)
>      N TB/2.5-inch (15.0 mm z-height)
>      S TB/2.5-inch (7 mm z-height)
>      T TB/2.5-inch (12.5 mm z-height)
> 4. **Business Unit/Brand**
>      A Desktop/WD Blue™; WD Green™; WD Black; WD Caviar®
>      B Enterprise/WD RE drive families (3-platter)
>      D Enterprise/WD Raptor®
>      E Mobile/WD Blue; WD Green; WD Black; WD Scorpio®
>      F Desktop NAS/WD Red™
>      H Enthusiast/WD VelociRaptor®
>      K Enterprise/WD XE; WD S25
>      L Enterprise/WD VelociRaptor
>      M Branded/WD Branded
>      N Branded Advanced Format/WD Branded
>      P Mobile Advanced Format/WD Blue; WD Green; WD Black; WD Scorpio
>      
>      R Enterprise Advanced Format/WD RE drive families
>      U Audio/Video Advanced Format - WD AV
>      V Audio/Video - WD AV
>      W Enterprise Advanced Format/WD VelociRaptor
>      Y Enterprise/WD RE drive families (4-platter)
>      Z Desktop Advanced Format/WD Blue; WD Black; WD Green; WD Caviar
> 5. **RPM/Buffer Size or Attribute**
>      A 5400 RPM with 2 MB cache
>      B 7200 RPM with 2 MB cache
>      C 5400 RPM with 16 MB cache
>      D 5400 RPM with 32 MB cache
>      E 7200 RPM with 64 MB cache (<2 TB)
>      F 10,000 RPM with 16 MB cache
>      G 10,000 RPM with 8 MB cache
>      H 10,000 RPM with 32 MB cache
>      J 7200 RPM with 8 MB cache
>      K 7200 RPM with 16 MB cache
>      L 7200 RPM with 32 MB cache
>      P IntelliPower™/EM (maximum buffer size offered by product)
>      R 5400 RPM with 64 MB cache
>      S 7200 RPM with 64 MB cache (2 TB)
>      T 10,000 RPM/EM (maximum buffer size offered by product)
>      V 5400 RPM with 8 MB cache (Mobile)
>      Y 7200 RPM/EM (maximum buffer size offered by product)
> 6. **Interface/Connector**
>      A ATA/66 with 40-pin IDE connector
>      B ATA/100 with 40-pin IDE connector
>      C ATA with 33-pin connector (zero insertion force—ZIF)
>      D SATA 1.5 Gb/s with 22-pin SATA connector
>      E ATA/133 with 40-pin IDE connector
>      F SAS-3 with 29-pin connector
>      G SAS-6 with 29-pin connector
>      S SATA 3 Gb/s with 22-pin SATA connector
>         SATA 1.5 Gb/s with 22-pin SATA connector (Mobile)
>      T SATA 3 Gb/s with 22-pin SATA connector (Mobile)
>      X SATA 3 Gb/s, 6 Gb/s capable with 22-pin SATA connector
>      Z SATA 6 Gb/s with 22-pin SATA connector
>
>    Subsequent updates to these definitions will be available in
>      Change Administration’s Model Specification (document number
>      2096-000101).  WD intranet access is required to view
>      or download the document.  To access the document, go to:
>      http://dna.wdc.com/dna/dnaspecs/ui/specECO/latestspec.aspx?specId=0
>      (DNA login required).
>
> #### Model Number Suffix
>
> The model number suffix (characters to the right of the dash
>   following the model number) is only for in-house use.
>
> #### Legacy Model Numbers
>
> For instructions on how to decipher WD internal drive model
>   numbers issued prior to December 2005, refer to the Legacy
>   Model and Order Numbers information sheet (2579-701261). 
>   A copy is available from your WD representative if required.

Comment: The document you've cited here is document number *2579-001028*, and it's available here: https://products.wdc.com/library/Flyer/ENG/2579-001028.pdf